# Err_too_many_redirects due to HTACCESS file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I hope you can help me. I'm gettting the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in my main page. https://docentesdecentes.com/
I try to change something in my htaccess file but I messed it up and the error appeared. I returned back to the previous file but it still persists. I do not understand what is happening. Could you help me?
I leave here my htaccess file so maybe you can find something wrong.

```
RewriteEngine on
# Diferenciar carpeta y archivo quitando slash
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} recursos-educacion-infantil/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} recursos-educacion-primaria/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} recursos-generales/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} imagenes-sin-fondo/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} apps-y-webs-educativas/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1

#urls amigables
RewriteRule ^recurso/(.*)$ recurso.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog.php?slug=$1
RewriteRule ^apps-y-webs-educativas/para-alumnos/(.*)$ apps-y-webs-educativas/para-alumnos.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^recursos-educacion-primaria/curso-(.*)$ recursos-educacion-primaria/curso.php?curso=$1
RewriteRule ^recursos-educacion-primaria/asignatura-([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?$ recursos-educacion-primaria/asignatura.php?asignatura=$1&curso=$3
RewriteRule ^recursos-educacion-infantil/tema-(.*)$ recursos-educacion-infantil/tema.php?tema=$1
RewriteRule ^recursos-generales/tema-(.*)$ recursos-generales/tema.php?tema=$1
RewriteRule ^imagenes-sin-fondo/imagenesde/(.*)$ imagenes-sin-fondo/imagenesde.php?tema=$1
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^avisos/(.*)$ /avisos.php?id=$1

# Quitar la extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
#para que no se pierdan los datos de formularios
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

## REDIRECCIONAR ##
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

## HTTP A HTTPS ##
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

## www to nonwww ##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.docentesdecentes.
RewriteRule ^ https://docentesdecentes.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You can debug that yourself: start reading about "rewrite logging" in the documentation of the rewriting module. It offers you detailed insight into what is actually going on inside your rewriting engine when a request is processed.

Comment: Also you should be able to see the series of redirections received by your browser in the console. That should also give you a hint what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! it was a problem of the server's caché.